# MYSQL query issue - join product details into result

Tags: mysql, database, join, product

I want to get some data out of my database that is similar to a receipt you get at the supermarket (just an example which suits kinda good to my real situation).
For example you get the 2 (always only 2) products 1 and 3. These products are stored in a seperated product database.
Your shopping result is stored in one database containing all the details like time, location and so on AND in 2 columns (product_1, and product_2). Again this shopping situation is only a comparison to my real situation so I know that this would not be a good database structure for a shopping list.

So now I would like to get the Whole receipt but instead of printing the product IDs I would like to have the Name and for example the price on it.

If I had only one product I would use this query:

```
SELECT `list`.`time`, `list`.`location`, `prod`.`prod_name`, `prod`.`prod_price`
FROM `shopping_list` `list`, `products` `prod`
WHERE `list`.`product_1` = `prod`.`prod_id`
```

But since I have two products I cannot just go on with

```
AND `list`.`product_2` = `prod`.`prod_id`
```

But how do you achive what I would like to have?

Thank you very much,
Phil

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to join to the product table twice

e.g.

```
SELECT 
      `list`.`time`, 
      `list`.`location`, 
      `prod1`.`prod_name` `prod_name1`, 
      `prod1`.`prod_price` `prod_price1` ,
      `prod2`.`prod_name` `prod_name2`, 
      `prod2`.`prod_price` `prod_price2` 
FROM `shopping_list` `list`
     INNER JOIN  `products` `prod1`
     ON  `list`.`product_1` = `prod1`.`prod_id`     
      INNER JOIN  `products` `prod2`
     ON  `list`.`product_2` = `prod2`.`prod_id`
```

I'm not sure what your business rules are so you may need to convert the second INNER JOIN to a LEFT JOIN if they need to always select two products.

Comment: I think I just did a similar thing by myself (Just the way I do in the question but with the FROM table twice like you do with prod1 and prod2 so without Joins but with WHERE). So this pretty much solves the problem but when I fetch the result into an array with php I have the prod_name and so twice as an index. Any solution how I could mark them as prod_name1 and prod_name2 or how I could deal with that situation... Thank you very much! :)

Comment: You can use column aliases. They work the same as table aliases. I've updated the answer to reflect this.

Comment: WOW. Good to know :) Thank you very much. I think this solves all my problems now. Always good to know what features the technology you use has to offer.

Answer (score 0):

i don't know your exact situation but usually field names like product_1 and product_2 indicate bad database design. however if you really need that you need to join the products table twice.

```
select
 * 
from
 list l
 , product p1
 , product p2
where
  l.product_1 = p1.product_id
  and l.product_2 = p2.product_id
```

(this is oracle syntax but i think it will work also in mysql).

hth.

Comment: yes as I mentioned above I do not use it for a product list or something like that. In my case it is a sport event (with time, league, popularity and so on) and prod1 is the home team and prod2 the guest team which are both stored in a `clubs` table with more detailed information about them. I think this way the structure is more reasonable or?

Comment: yes i agree, for something like this the structure is perfectly fine :)

Answer (score 0):

The previous answers work well if you can parse out the two lines from 1 database result row. If you want two lines from the database you could do a UNION query:

```
SELECT `list`.`time`, `list`.`location`, `prod`.`prod_name`, `prod`.`prod_price`  
FROM `shopping_list` `list`, `products` `prod`  
WHERE `list`.`product_1` = `prod`.`prod_id` 
UNION
SELECT `list`.`time`, `list`.`location`, `prod`.`prod_name`, `prod`.`prod_price`  
FROM `shopping_list` `list`, `products` `prod`  
WHERE `list`.`product_2` = `prod`.`prod_id`
```

Comment: A friend of mine told me that I should just use UNION but had no time to explain it in more detail. So thank you very much for your example! I am not sure if it makes a difference which way you use.